# R - Using previous row value on the fly

Tags: r, data.table

I'm pretty new with R and I followed many tutorials those last weeks to improve myself on it.

I'm trying to achieve something I'm not sure I can with R. I want, from a dataset, compute a new value using value of this dataset from different row.

I got a simple input table like this :

```
   InVal
1:   100
2:    10
3:    -5
4:    10
```

And I want to compute, for each line, the sum of InVal if it is positive and reuse previous result of InVal if not.

For this purpose I created a new col and initialize it with 0 and add a 0-row for initData:

```
   InVal Result
1:     0      0
2:   100      0
3:    10      0
4:    -5      0
5:    10      0
```

Then I tried this expecting it would do the job:

```
DT[ , Result := InVal + shift(Result, 1L, type="lag")]
```

But I'm obtaining this:

```
   InVal Result
1:     0     NA
2:   100    100
3:    10     10
4:    -5     -5
5:    10     10
```

It seems R i using 0 as Result for all rows and not the actual result computing the row before. I thought R was executing sequentially ?!

Do you have any idea how can I achieve my goal ?
Thanks :)

Comment: what is your expected output?

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that you want a cumulative sum of the series , but want to copy the sum from previous row where the value is less than zero. This can be done by replacing all the -ve values with 0 and then finding a `cumsum`.

```
require(data.table)

dt=data.table(Inval=c(100,10,-5,10))
dt

dt[,Result:= Inval]
dt
dt[Result<0, Result:=0 ]
dt

dt[, Result:=cumsum(Result)]
dt
```

Comment: Alternately `dt[, cumsum(Inval*(Inval>0))]`, I guess.

Comment: Yes sir, indeed. Though multiplication with boolean might confuse some, this is definitely  the shortest  and sleek way of doing it.

Comment: Thank you very much guys, That's exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: @user2436914 :   Would you please accept this as answer then? Or if you are using Frank's version then you can ask him if he would like to post his comment as answer so you can accept it.

Comment: I unfortunately cannot ... SOrry

Comment: That's fine. you're welcome for appreciating and replying.